# Kill Local Process

Tags: .net, vb.net, process, kill-process

I am using the below to kill local processes:

```
Sub KillProcess(ByVal ProcessName As String)
        Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName)
        pProcess(0).Kill()
    End Sub
```

I call the above with the below:

```
Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
        KillProcess("acsAPP")
        KillProcess("acsSRV")
        KillProcess("ACSTrans")
        KillProcess("acsCNTRL")
        KillProcess("acsRep")
    End Sub
```

Apparently, the above only kills the parent process and not the entire tree(multiple processes running under same name).  How can i kill all processes listed with the same name?  There has to be a force switch or something like that.

Thanks!

Comment: GetProcessesByName returns more than one, but you are only deleting the first one. Loop through all the results and kill each seems easiest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in your `KillProcess()`, you are only killing 1 process, while the `GetProcessesByName()` is returning a list of processes. Try replacing your method with the below, by looping through all the processes and kill them all;

```
Private Sub KillProcess(ByVal ProcessName As String)

    Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName)

    For Each p As Process In pProcess
        p.Kill()
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the docs on [GetProcessByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see it returns an *Array* of processes matching the name (there is no such thing as a process tree by the way as there is no hierarchy of processes).

You are only killing the first one in the array: `pProcess(0)`. Note `(0)` is the first element in the array as it is zero based.

To fix this you need to kill all processes that match:

```
Sub KillProcess(ByVal ProcessName As String)
    For Each proc As Process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName)
        proc.Kill()
    Next
End Sub
```